# IOS- Cross command is not working- 'ios64-cross' or `iphoneos-cross'

Tags: ios, ssl, openssl, pjsip

I'm integrate PJSIP Lib with video calling and want to apply TLS/Openssl Configuration
using https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#iOS link.
But i'm facing below error.

```
apple@iMac pjproject-master-4 % ./Configure ios64-cross no-shared no-dso no-hw no-engine --prefix=/usr/local/openssl-ios64
aconfigure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
aconfigure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
aconfigure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
aconfigure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
aconfigure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `ios64-cross': machine `ios64' not recognized
aconfigure: error: /bin/sh ./config.sub ios64-cross failed
```

and

```
./Configure iphoneos-cross --prefix=/Users/teluu/openssl-1.1.0f-iphone64/arm64

aconfigure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `iphoneos-cross': machine `iphoneos' not recognized
aconfigure: error: /bin/sh ./config.sub iphoneos-cross failed
```

Any help should be highly appreciated.

Thank You.